# CSS Body min-height infinite scrolling

Tags: javascript, css

I have this code in my Laravel CSS

```
 var setContentHeight = function() {

 $RIGHT_COL.css('min-height', $(window).height());
```

With this css, my webpage DIV min height is increasing infinitely thus scrolling the webpage automatically.

I would like to know an alternative for : $RIGHT_COL.css('min-height', $(window).height());

when i changed the css with the following code its working fine. Just want to know is there a better option handling this error.

```
 $RIGHT_COL.css({'min-height':"100%"});
```

Or is there any better option handling such issues.

Thanx in advance

Comment: Does setContentHeight function get attached to a scroll event ?

Comment: Yes it is attached .